# Magento 2 - Prevent addresses to be saved when placing order

Tags: magento2, php

When a customer is placing an order its addresses are automatically saved, I would like to prevent this behavior but I'm not able to find in which file Magento is saving addresses ?

Comment: why you want to prevent this ?

Comment: Because I don't want the customer to be able to add new address and as he can use address from another customer account he could be able to add a new one if Magento is saving it automatically

Comment: How one customer can use address from other customer on checkout ?